Dark matter detector experiments above ground?
Most of the dark matter detectors I hear about are built below ground to shield from cosmic rays. One problem I see with this is what if the ground is also shielding dark matter from interacting with the experiment?
Are there any studies that have looked for dark matter interactions above ground (besides annihilation/gamma ray detectors)?
Why should I expect dark matter to be diffuse and detectable below ground?

IDK, but I'm guessing that cosmologists would not consider any form of matter that is stopped by the Earth's crust to be a dark matter candidate (I.e., they would not expect it to be "dark.")

Indeed, being stopped by a bit of earth means depositing energy into it, which would mean there is pretty strong interactions with regular matter including ionizing it.

Axion detectors don't need shielding: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axion_Dark_Matter_Experiment

@SolomonSlow Not necessarily. There's a legitimate window for dark matter-baryon interactions that are too strong to be detected in the underground experiments but still weak enough to behave like collisionless dark matter on the scales that we've observed.

Dark matter is almost non-interacting. So it hardly interacts with the Earth at all. If it did, it wouldn't be dark matter. The point of putting the experiments below ground is to reduce all the spurious background events that are difficult to distinguish from the rare dark matter events of interest.
As FlatterMann points out, the ADMX search for axion dark matter does not need to be sited below ground. That is because it is searching for a weak microwave signal caused by axion decay and the principal source of noise is thermal photons in the apparatus, rather than a particle background.

There is a wide range of efforts to use astronomical observations to put limits on dark matter-Standard Model (DM-SM) interactions that are too strong to be detected underground. From the introduction of a recent paper:

Terrestrial laboratory searches for DM require the interaction strength of DM with baryonic matter to be sufficiently weak to permit the DM to traverse both the atmosphere and the experimental shielding. By contrast, some astrophysical targets are naturally unshielded and can directly constrain models where the DM-SM coupling exceeds thresholds for detectability in surface and subterranean detectors.
The DM-baryon interaction cross section can be indirectly, yet strongly, constrained using cosmological and astrophysical observables. In the early universe, strongly-coupled DM can distort the spectrum of cosmic microwave background (CMB) and acts to smooth out its measured temperature anisotropies [1–8]. At late times DM will also impede the formation of small-scale structure which is measurable through observations of, e.g., Milky Way satellites [9, 10] and the Lyman-α forest [11]. Furthermore, DM-baryonic scattering can heat up gas-rich dwarf galaxies with measurably small radiative cooling rates [12, 13]

